# What is the difference between "predict" and "predict_class" functions in keras?

Tags: keras

What is the difference between `predict` and `predict_class` functions in keras?

Why does `Model` object don't have `predict_class` function?

Answer (score 47):

`predict` will return the scores of the regression and `predict_class` will return the class of your prediction. Although it seems similar, there are some differences:

Imagine you are trying to predict if the picture is a dog or a cat (you have a classifier):

- `predict` will return you: 0.6 cat and 0.4 dog (for example).
- `predict_class` will return the index of the class having maximum value. For example, if cat is 0.6 and dog is 0.4, it will return 0 if the class cat is at index 0)

Now, imagine you are trying to predict house prices (you have a regressor):

- `predict` will return the predicted price
- `predict_class` will not make sense here since you do not have a classifier

TL:DR: use `predict_class` for classifiers (outputs are labels) and use `predict` for regressions (outputs are non-discrete)

Hope it helps!

For your second question, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes)

Comment: if 'predict_class' function is used for classification task, why does Model object don't have this function?

Comment: I encountered this problem when I was browsing the stackoverflow, not when I was coding. I found it a bit strange because the task types handled by the two models should be similar. Since the Model object can deal with classification task, it should have 'predict_classes' function.

Comment: can you supply more info? links maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes

Comment: This is the link. It just said there is no 'predict_classes' function in Model object, but it didn't say why. Anyway, thank you all the same.

Comment: The anwser of your question is the answer of the post you gave me, what is it you dont understand? (Trying to help here). This is the answer: `The predict_classes method is only available for the Sequential class (which is the class of your first model) but not for the Model class (the class of your second model).

With the Model class, you can use the predict method which will give you a vector of probabilities and then get the argmax of this vector (with np.argmax(y_pred1,axis=1)).`

Answer (score 8):

**predict_classes** method is only available for the **Sequential class**  but not for the Model class 
[You can check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `Model` object don't have `predict_class` function?

The answer was given here in this [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2524#issuecomment-218590463). (Nevertheless, this is still a very complex explanation. Any help is welcomed)

> For models that have more than one output, these concepts are
> ill-defined. And it would be a bad idea to make available something in
> the one-output case but not in other cases (inconsistent API).
>
> For the Sequential model, the reason this is supported is for
> backwards compatibility only.

Predict_class is missing from the functional API.