# How to save a trained model in Keras to use it in an application?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, machine-learning-model

I have trained a model in Keras, and saved it in different ways like;

```
model.save("filename")
```

or

```
model.to_json()  
model.save_weights("filename")
```

But when I load the trained model in another program to make predictions, I get very different results from the test results.

Why does that happens and how can I handle that?

Comment: Oh, I have solve it by saving the model as '.yaml' file instead '.json'. Then, load the weights and compile it.

Answer (score 3):

save it like:

```
     model.save('model.h5')
     model_json = model.to_json()
     with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
         json_file.write(model_json)
```

Then for loading it into application efficiently, make it a global like following so that it doesn't load again and again:

```
    def load_model():

        global model

        json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
        model_json = json_file.read()
        model = model_from_json(model_json)
        model.load_weights("model.h5")
        model._make_predict_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the model in .h5 format

```
from keras.models import model_from_json   
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = parallel_model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Answer (score 0):

> also, You can do this way

**Save model**

```
 model.save('clasification_model.h5')
```

**Read Model**

```
from keras.models import load_model
classifier = load_model('clasification_model.h5')
```

**Prediction**

```
res = classifier.predict_classes(x, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

[classifier.predict_classes vs classifier.predict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382524/what-is-the-difference-between-predict-and-predict-class-functions-in-keras)

[keras Sequential model API](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/)