# Check if the way of evaluating keras model via unseen data is correct

Tags: keras, neural-network

I studied `Keras` and created my first neural network model as the following:

```
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
from keras import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

tr_X, tr_y = getTrainingData()

# NN Architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=tr_X.shape[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.advanced_activations.PReLU())

model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(keras.layers.advanced_activations.PReLU())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the Model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the Model
model.fit(tr_X, tr_y, epochs=1000, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.2)

# ----- Evaluate the Model (Using UNSEEN data) ------
ts_X, ts_y = getTestingData()
yhat_classes = model.predict_classes(ts_X, verbose=0)[:, 0]
accuracy = accuracy_score(ts_y, yhat_classes)
print(accuracy)
```

I am not sure about the last portion of my code, i.e., model evaluation using `model.predict_classes()` where new data are loaded via a custom method `getTestingData()`. See my goal is to test the final model using new UNSEEN data to evaluate its prediction. My question is about this part: Am I evaluating the model correctly?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You can use predict or predict_classes to get the predictions on test data. If you need the loss & metrics directly, you can use the evaluate method by feeding ts_X and ts_y.

```
y_pred = model.predict(ts_X)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(ts_X, ts_y)
```

https://keras.io/models/model/#predict

https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate

Difference between predict & predict_classes: [What is the difference between "predict" and "predict_class" functions in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382524/what-is-the-difference-between-predict-and-predict-class-functions-in-keras)