# 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' in R Keras multi-gpu model

Tags: r, keras

I am using keras in R for a classification problem.

I used  `model <- keras_model_sequential()` with 3 layers

```
parallel.model <- multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)

parallel.model %>% compile(
  loss = loss_binary_crossentropy,
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = 0.001, epsilon = 1e-08),
  metrics = c("accuracy"))

parallel.model %>% fit(
  train.x,
  y.train,
  epochs = 50,
  batch_size = 256,
  validation_split = 0.2)
```

When I used

```
 y.test.hat <- parallel.model %>% predict_classes(test.y)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
Calls: %>% ... py_get_attr_or_item -> py_get_attr -> py_get_attr_impl
```

Is it because parallel.model is not sequential? Because I got the same error when I used:

```
 parallel.model %>% pop_layer()
```

Comment: Leave the pipe operator aside and try `y.test.hat <-  predict_classes(parallel.model, test.x)` (I suppose `test.y` you have in your code is a typo); does it work?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I got this error:                                                                             AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict\_classes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes)