# Even when using Sequential model, I am getting "AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' "

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, recurrent-neural-network

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes) question that we need sequential model to use `.predict_classes` I am using this model but still getting

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

error. I am using following code

```
def Build_Model_RNN_Text(word_index, embeddings_index, nclasses,  MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=500, EMBEDDING_DIM=50, dropout=0.5):
 
    model = Sequential()
    hidden_layer = 3
    gru_node = 32    
    embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
    for word, i in word_index.items():
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
            if len(embedding_matrix[i]) != len(embedding_vector):
                print("could not broadcast input array from shape", str(len(embedding_matrix[i])),
                      "into shape", str(len(embedding_vector)), " Please make sure your"
                                                                " EMBEDDING_DIM is equal to embedding_vector file ,GloVe,")
                exit(1)
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                trainable=True))
    print(gru_node)
    for i in range(0,hidden_layer):
        model.add(GRU(gru_node,return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(GRU(gru_node, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(nclasses, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Even when using `.predict`, instead of `.predict_classes` get I am getting same error

EDIT: I am using following code to call method

```
predicted = Build_Model_RNN_Text.predict_classes(X_test_Glove)
```

Comment: I don't see where you're attempting to call `.predict_classes`, but from the error clearly you're trying to do so on a `function` object. Please provide the code you're running when you encounter this error. Seems like a syntax error.

Comment: I have added code to call method kindly have a look

Comment: It's exactly as I expected. You're not calling your function `Build_Model_RNN_Text`, which means it's not returning anything. You need to **call** your function in order to get its output.

Comment: can you tell me how am I not calling function here? I can't understand as I have called other models in same way

Comment: You call functions in Python by using `()`, like `my_function()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you were not calling your function in order to get its output. Simply do

```py
predicted = Build_Model_RNN_Text(<<args>>).predict_classes(X_test_Glove)
```

Where you need to replace `<<args>>` with the required arguments for your function. It seems like maybe you had intended for `Build_Model_RNN_Text` to be a `class` instead?

Either way, how exactly were you expecting this to work, as you were not providing the required arguments `word_index`, `embeddings_index`, and `nclasses`...