# AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

in google colaboratory using python, I am trying to load model to classify
I am trying to load keras model using python to classify image, I am getting above error

Comment: No error posted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict\_classes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806125/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes)

Answer (score 0):

`predict_classes` is only available for the `Sequential` class.

With the Model class, you can use the `predict` method which will give you a vector of probabilities and then get the `argmax` of this vector (with `np.argmax(y_pred1,axis=1)`).